# Formatting JTable data on an html file

Tags: java, formatting, jtable

I have a `JTable` and a `JButton`. I want to save the `JTable` data into an `HTML` file.

Here is part of the code that does this:

```
else if (ae.getSource().equals(save)) {
            try {
                try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\nationch\\Desktop\\table.html", true))) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < table.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                        bw.write(table.getColumnName(col));
                        bw.write("\t");
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
                        bw.newLine();
                        for (int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                            bw.write((String) (table.getValueAt(i, j)));
                            bw.write("\t");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(jtable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
```

The code is working fine for a text file. The data is being saved as shown below in bold
**Name       Surname

Nation  Chirara 
Bill         Thompson

Bates       Charlie**

When I removed the `.txt` and replaced it with a`.html` as shown here

```
 new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\nationch\\Desktop\\table.html", true)))
```

the code worked fine except formatting. The data was formatted as follows

**Name Surname Nation Chirara Bill Thompson Bates Charlie**

How do we get this formatted as the first output from a text file?

Comment: in order to render html you need to use HTML tags

Comment: @Peter  great i had forgotten my HTML. So in this case which html tag is the equivalent of "\t"

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a JTable `table`, use this to produce an unadorned HTML table to `bw`:

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
bw.write("<table>");
for(int r=0;r<model.getRowCount();++r) {
    bw.write("<tr>");
    for(int c=0;c<model.getColumnCount();++c) {
        bw.write("<td>");
        bw.write(model.getValueAt(r,c).toString());
        bw.write("</td>");
    }
}
bw.write("</table>");
```